# Azure AD Authentication ASP.NET 4.8 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have been tasked to investigate and also develop support for Azure AD in our existing ASP .NET 4.8 (Not Core) Web Forms application.

The current application connects directly to a SQL database that contains the usernames and passwords and that is how we authenticate. We have a requirement to add Azure AD authentication to this but I am unsure of how this can be achieved and I can only find examples based on .NET Core 5 later.

We plan on hosting the Database in the cloud through Azure and provide Azure Virtual Desktops to use the Windows 10 client. However, we want to host the .NET 4.8 application also on Azure and have it secured with Azure AD. Any guidance on how this could be achieved or a some resources to investigate would be perfect. Since this site maybe replicates for different tenents/customers it would need to be configurable to change which Azure AD it is conencted to.

Thanks.